# finding a unknown with recursive Binary Search

Tags: java, sorting, binary-search

So, I'm working on a program designed to find a pivot point in a sorted array, and I'm using binary search as it needs to have a Big O of OlogN. I've been doing some JUnit testing, and I noticed that my code doesn't return the right value. When I step through the code, it gets the right value, but then keeps on going and then returns the wrong answer? I've been doing a lot of pen and paper testing and it should return the number in theory.

The test I'm doing is to check to see how the program will respond if the index is left of the middle.
Also, when I'm doing a test to check to see if the index is right of the middle, I get infinite recursion?

I'm not asking for a solution, but a pointer to something or somewhere I might be missing something, because as the coder I realize I may have a hard time critiquing my own code.

```
 * Author: XXX
 *
 * This program is designed to find the pivot point in an array sorted in ascending order
 * that is rotated at some pivot unknown to you beforehand.
 */


package algorithmAssignment;

public class pivotFinder {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // testing
        int[] arr = new int[] {26, 28, 32, 1, 5, 6, 9, 10, 22};
        
        int result = findPivot(arr, arr.length - 1, 0, arr.length/2);
        
        // expected index of 3
        System.out.println(result);

    }

    static int findPivot(int[] arr, int max, int min, int pivot) { // feeding in arr, max, min, and pivot point

        // base case
        if (max - min < 1) {
            return pivot;
        }

        // binary search
        if (arr[pivot] < arr[max]) {
            findPivot(arr, pivot, min, pivot / 2); // return the arr, the pivot as the new max, and the new pivot
        } else {
            findPivot(arr, max, pivot, max - (pivot / 2)); // return the arr, the pivot as the new min, and the new
                                                            // pivot
        }

        return pivot; //unsure why I need this
    }

}
```

Also, why do I need the last line returning the pivot? I'm using eclipse and it said that the method had to return a type of int, but doesn't it already do that? I'm wondering if this could be my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
findPivot(arr, pivot, min, pivot / 2); // return the arr, the pivot as the new max, and the new pivot
```

does not return anything. You just forgot to add the return keyword. (Also 2 lines later you forget it, too). Adding the two returns, your last line returning the pivot can be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

I tried editing @maxemann96 's answer, but the "Suggested edit queue is full".

In other words, what maxemann96 tried to say is that you're ignoring the search results altogether.

You could try replacing your `findPivot` method to something like this:

```java
    // feeding in arr, max, min, and pivot point
    static int findPivot(int[] arr, int max, int min, int pivot) {
    
        // base case
        if (max - min < 1) {
            return pivot;
        }

        // binary search
        if (arr[pivot] < arr[max]) {
             // return the arr, the pivot as the new max, and the new pivot
            return findPivot(arr, pivot, min, pivot / 2);
        }
        
        // return the arr, the pivot as the new min, and the new pivot
        return findPivot(arr, max, pivot, max - (pivot / 2));
    }
```